# jQuery.active dont updated properly after js error in ajax callback

Tags: jquery

For see thar error just

1. Write in console:

   $.get("/", function(){

   throw "test"; //any error here, manually throwed or runtime error

   });
2. See error throwed 
   "Uncaught test"
3. Check $.active == 1 forever
4. $(document).on("ajaxStop"... callback now will not be called forever

jquery 1.10.
What can i do to prevent this issue?

Comment: Can't you use try and catch in your response handler ??

Comment: Yes i can. But that jquery behavior is not clean, isn't it?

Comment: I faced similar issue today!! There were even few bugs logged around this -
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13680
http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11207
But are closed saying invalid!!! I guess its needs to be handled manually using try and catch block around the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .ajaxError().

```
$( document ).ajaxError(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxError handler." );
});
```

more Details : http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/

Comment: Won't that only trigger when there's an error in the actual ajax result? Because the actual request seems to work fine, the error is thrown (manually) in the callback.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. i mis-interpreted the question.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using try - catch in success and fail callback function, I simply logged the error in catch block and then it works fine.